# Need to add DISTINCT to Join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use DISTINCT in my query, but I am not able to get the syntax correct to get the result that i am expecting.  I made a couple different stack overflow posts, and I think I finally understand how to include all of the information i need to get help.

I built a shared space on DB Fiddle with all of the information already loaded here:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b2o3Wy31hLmwSZLAfpuaVr/0#&togetherjs=IrGzVdtmMh

```
CREATE TABLE hosts (
  hostid INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (hostid),
  UNIQUE (name)
);
INSERT INTO hosts 
    (hostid, name) 
VALUES 
    (10761,"CUCM1"),
    (10762,"CUCM2"),
    (10763,"CUCM3");

CREATE TABLE items (
  hostid INT NOT NULL,
  itemid INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  valuemapid INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO items 
    (hostid,itemid,name,valuemapid) 
VALUES 
(10761,304827,"Phone 33 44 55 66 77 88:Model of the Phone",68),
--phone1
(10761,304827,"Phone 33 44 55 66 77 88:Model of the Phone",68), 
--phone1
(10761,304827,"Phone 33 44 55 66 77 88:Model of the Phone",68), 
--phone1
(10761,304828,"Phone 33 44 55 66 88 88:Model of the Phone",68), 
--phone2
(10761,304828,"Phone 33 44 55 66 88 88:Model of the Phone",68), 
--phone2
(10761,304828,"Phone 33 44 55 66 88 88:Model of the Phone",68), 
--phone2
(10761,304829,"Phone 33 44 55 77 77 88:Model of the Phone",68), 
--phone3
(10761,304829,"Phone 33 44 55 77 77 88:Model of the Phone",68), 
--phone3
(10761,304820,"Phone 33 44 44 66 77 88:Model of the Phone",72), 
--phone4
(10761,304820,"Phone 33 44 44 66 77 88:Model of the Phone",72); 
--phone4

CREATE TABLE history_uint (
  itemid INT NOT NULL,
  value INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO history_uint 
    (itemid,value) 
VALUES 
(304827,109),
(304828,109),
(304829,109),
(304820,110);

CREATE TABLE mappings (
  valuemapid INT NOT NULL,
  value INT NOT NULL,
  newvalue VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (valuemapid)
);

INSERT INTO mappings 
    (valuemapid,value,newvalue) 
VALUES 
(68,109,"Cisco 7841"),
(72,110,"Cisco 7940");
```

And here is my Query that i have been able to piece together

```
SELECT map.newvalue as 'Model of Phone', Count(*) as 'Number of Phones'
FROM hosts h
    LEFT JOIN items i
        ON h.hostid=i.hostid
    LEFT JOIN history_uint huint
        ON i.itemid=huint.itemid
    LEFT JOIN mappings map
        ON i.valuemapid=map.valuemapid
WHERE huint.value=map.value AND i.name LIKE '%Model of the Phone'
GROUP BY map.newvalue;
```

Right now the query returns

```
Model of Phone  Number of Phones
Cisco 7841      8
Cisco 7940      2
```

But i am hoping to use DISTINCT on the items table colomn itemid so we only get back

```
Model of Phone  Number of Phones
Cisco 7841      3
Cisco 7940      1
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Grouping by a column from the right most table in a LEFT JOIN makes (usually) not much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happen if you `DISTINCT` the `COUNT`?

```
SELECT map.newvalue as 'Model of Phone'
    , Count(DISTINCT i.name) as 'Number of Phones'
FROM hosts h
JOIN items i ON h.hostid = i.hostid
JOIN history_uint huint ON i.itemid = huint.itemid
JOIN mappings map ON i.valuemapid = map.valuemapid AND huint.value=map.value 
WHERE i.name LIKE '%Model of the Phone'
GROUP BY map.newvalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically want distinct records from the items table which will give you the phone type, your query should probably look like the following:

```
SELECT map.newvalue as 'Model of Phone', Count(distinct i.itemid) as 
'Number of Phones'
FROM hosts h
LEFT JOIN items i
    ON h.hostid=i.hostid
LEFT JOIN history_uint huint
    ON i.itemid=huint.itemid
LEFT JOIN mappings map
    ON i.valuemapid=map.valuemapid
WHERE huint.value=map.value AND i.name LIKE '%Model of the Phone'
GROUP BY map.newvalue;
```

When you did a count(*) the reason why it returned 8 rows as the count was because each row renders distinct when you add the itemid (from history_uint) to the select fields. So collectively, the fields were not distinct thus returning all 8 rows.

Comment: Thank you raj... Eric just barely posted it before you did but thank you for the help as well and the detailed explination